# How do i make a "Non clickable" option in drop-down JoptionPane message box

Tags: java, messagebox

```
    String[] choices = {"Today", "Tomorrow", **"-------------"**, "Exit"};
    String picked = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Where to: ", "Travel!", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices [0]);
```

How (If there is a way) do i make the "-----------" in String[] choices a non clickable button so i can separate options easier without error messages if they click on the "------------"

If there are any other methods to getting around this, like adding a loop, let me know, im new-ish to java and probably won't know how to make the loop

Comment: Kinda, sorta can't be done...

Comment: `JOptionPane` allows you to provide your own component which can be displayed (instead of the message).  You could add a `separator` to the combobox, but it's not without some work.  Take a look [at this example](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jcombobox_items_with_separators) for deatils on the combo box side of things...